# Can boot Debian Linux only pressing F12 key

Tags: linux, boot, debian

I installed Debian Linux (version 9.5) on a Dell Precision 7720 laptop, and it is the only operating system.
Everything works as expected, but it does not boot correctly.

If I boot the computer without pressing any key, I get this error:

```
No bootable devices found.
Press F1 key to retry boot.
Press F2 key for setup utility.
Press F5 key to run onboard diagnostics.
```

From the setup utility everything seems to be fine.

During the installation, I created a dedicated boot partition.

To have a successful boot, I need to keep the F12 key pressed during startup (where I am allowed to boot either from the hard disk or the network, setup the BIOS, change boot settings, ...), and opt to boot from my local hard disk. Doing so the hard disk is found, and everything works correctly from here.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What does the F12 key do? Have you got the boot order / priority correct?

Comment: This could happen if you are trying to legacy boot an EFI-configured system, or vice versa. It might be a good idea to run `sudo update-grub` after you manage to get the system booted and see what systems are found.

Comment: @Attie - I expanded my question.